# Access to ptr to array of node handle c++

Tags: c++

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct  edagroup 
{
    UINT16  nodes;  /* # slots - may not all be in use */
    EHANDLE *eh;    /* ptr to array of node handles */
} *GNUM;
```

And this:

```
typedef struct ehandle 
{
    UINT32    is_tag256;    /* Is the remote node 256 character?  */
    UINT32    is_tag30 ;    /* Is the remote node 30 character?  */
}*EHANDLE;
```

And this method:

```
GNUM    sample_call(UINT16 n_nodes, INT16 detect_changes);
```

We call to this method that returns a GNUM struture and I want to access to **is_tag256** property.

Sample:

```
GNUM FixGroupInit  = sample_call(1, 0); 
EHANDLE *eh = FixGroupInit->eh;
...
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a chain of pointers that leads ot an *array* of `ehandle`, not just one. *Which* `is_tag256` do you want? (I think you are using more pointers than are needed.)

Comment: Thanks!
These structures are from the API that I should use, I cannot change them.
What I need is to access the is_tag256 property of the ehandle structure. The only thing I have is the sample_call method

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need `typedef struct`; only use the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to tell us where the *array* comes in (and there is an ambiguity in the code comments -- the author of that API ought to be beaten with a stick) but you can try this:

```
(**(FixGroupInit->eh)).is_tag256
```